# Safari Javascript is conflicting JSON item with keyword

Tags: javascript, safari

I have the following JSON data:

```
{"data":{
            "default":"some data"
         }
}
```

Whenever I try to access `data.default`, Safari generates sytax error because the keyword `default`. Other web browsers seem to work.

What is the work around for this type of issue?

note: I can't change the JSON data. It is out of my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data["default"]
```

works exactly the same, but takes a string

Answer (score 1):

Use `data["default"]` instead. The word *default*, normally used within switch statements, is contained within a string, so the JavaScript parser does not complain about an "unexpected keyword."

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var js = {"data":{
        "default":"some data"
     }
};
alert(js.data["default"]);
```